Advice Needed: Replacing Cast Iron Stack in 1925 Three-Family Home
I'm remodeling a three-family home built in 1925 (up-and-down layout). So far, I’ve gutted the first- and second-floor bathrooms down to the studs (they were all plaster and lath). All the plumbing and drainage is lead and cast iron, including the stack. I live on the third floor and need some advice about the stack:

Do I need to replace the cast iron stack with PVC, or is it better to leave the old cast iron in place?

If I switch to PVC, will noise be a major issue? Are there effective ways to mitigate noise from PVC stacks?

Since I live on the third floor, is it possible to replace only the bottom two-thirds of the stack (serving the first and second floors) and tackle the third floor and attic portion later, once the lower floors are finished?


For context, the basement portion of the stack is already PVC, but the rest is cast iron and runs through the roof. Are there any potential challenges or risks with replacing just the lower portion first and leaving the upper section for later?
Thanks for your insights!

What is the state of the cast iron stack now? Rusted through? Leaking? No problems?

Unless you can tell the pipes are in good condition, with the walls gutted now, it would be nice to replace since they might be end of life.  100 years is a good life for them.  Cast iron is heavy, so having helpers/ropes will be handy.

The stack itself has no issues except it's bowing the PVC section in the basement, probably it wasn't anchored properly. The horizontal pipes for shower and sink connected to the stack are pretty brittle and cracked while take the ceiling down. How would you go about replacing it? The tough part is that I live in the top floor, is there a way to replace the bottom 2/3 to finish 1st and 2nd floor and later tackle the 3rd floor and the attic portion?

Welcome. You're asking multiple questions here, which makes your post off topic. While they're loosely related, the are distinct questions (some of which are already answered here). Please see [ask] and take the [tour], then revise.

If you own all the units and have the rooms gutted and walls torn open, you absolutely should replace all the 100-year-old cast iron pipes in entirety.
In a single-family home, if you are renovating an upstairs bathroom with 70- or  80- year old cast iron, you would replace it and you might debate whether to open up the living room walls below and replace all of it,or wait for a downstairs renovation.
But here, ALL the ingredients for "do it now" are present:

It's 100 years old.  Nobody will argue that this will outlast new PVC
You have the walls open.  It would be crazy not to take advantage of this now
You have ALL the walls open.  Replacing cast iron fittings in the ceilings between floors is a lot easier if you have access from above AND below.  You have that now!
You will have tenants on the other floors.  That changes the math overwhelmingly.  If a 100-year-old pipe in the walls of a tenant's apartment cracks or fails, you then have to fix it with great urgency at higher cost and under the eye of your tenant.  You would SO regret not having done it now.

Further to your comments above and below:

Yes PVC is a lot noisier than cast iron.  But this is mainly a problem when it is open to the room.  For example in a playroom or workshop in an unfinished basement with drain pipes running along the walls or ceiling, you'll hear water flowing much more loudly.  But in a finished wall it's less of a problem.    You don't need to worry too much but if you want, mainly: avoid unnecessary changes of direction.
The transition from vertical to horizontal is where most of the noise is produced.  And avoid horizontal runs in walls adjacent to bedrooms.  If you are positioning the units at premium prices and want to play it safe you could stuff the joist bays with insulation and use double drywall.  I really don't think it's necessary though.
The remaining bit of cast iron through the roof can be hung from the rafters or supported by the attic floor.  If there is a cast iron hub in the attic, make the first cut below it so you can attach the PVC there and use the hub to hang the pipe.  Otherwise you'll need a hanger bracket.


Thanks for laying this out so clearly—it clears up all my doubts. I’ll replace all the cast iron up to the roofline, leaving just the small section through the roof for now to avoid breaking the watertight seal. I’ll replace that later when I do the roof. I just need to figure out how to anchor it securely.
For now, I’ll replace everything on the first, second, and third floors. The only cast iron left will be the small roof section and the horizontal part under the basement concrete. Thanks again for helping me solidify my plan!
